# In Moneycontrol's Login page , Selenium is unable to find the Webelementes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Moneycontrol's [website](http://www.moneycontrol.com/), I am unable to enter the username and password while trying to log in. Selenium is unable to find the Webelements.

```java
public void setUrl() throws IOException {
  driver = new FirefoxDriver()
  driver.get("http://www.moneycontrol.com/");
}

public void Login() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Log In']")).click();
    //enter user name and password

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='formbox']/div[1]/form/div[1]")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='pwd']")).sendKeys("Abc@92");
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGr3J.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **`Email or User ID`** field is within an `<iframe>`, so to invoke `sendKeys()` at **`Email or User ID`** and **`Password`** field you have to switch to the respective `<iframe>` as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://accounts.moneycontrol.com/mclogin/?d=2']")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login_form']//input[@class='textfield' and @id='email']")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='login_form']//input[@class='textfield' and @id='pwd']")).sendKeys("Abc@92");
```

Comment: Thank You ! It is working fine . Please explain how you found the xPath for this?
in firefox I am not able to find this webelement and there is no src with value "'https://accounts.moneycontrol.com/mclogin/?d=2']". 
I also didn't understand how you found out if there are iframes on this page, I didn't see them while looking up the firepath. kindly explain, thanks.

Comment: @Rajesh Finding the correct `xpath` is pretty easy. Downgrade your `Firefox` to v53.x sub levels where `Firebug` & `Firepath` is supported which clearly shows you the `Top Level Content` and the associated `Frames`. Soon you will come to an understanding how to detect `Frames`. Upgrade back to `Firefox Quantum` or `Chrome` and find the `Frames` easily through `Dev Tools` which is the best way to find any element. On `MoneyControl` site if you traverse up the `DOM` you will find the `<iframe>` tag with `src` with value set to accounts.moneycontrol.com/mclogin/?d=2

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Selenium with C#**
```

You need to switch to frames and in your case id of your frame is "myframe". Below is the working code for selenium with C#

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void moneyControl()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\Akash\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\");
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.moneycontrol.com/");
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title='Log In']")).Click();
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("myframe");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("pwd")).SendKeys("abc");

}
```

Comment: Thank you . It is working fine . There is some delay needed after clicking on Login option.

Comment: To learn how to deal with xpath you can refer http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium or https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html